# Mousewheel Event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mouseevent

I have got as form with a `vertical scroll bar`, I want to use the mouse wheel to scroll up and down the form but I cant seem to get to get the `mousewheel event` to fire.

I just use the standard `mousewheel` event

```
Private Sub frmTest_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseWheel

'code here

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to place a one `Panel` in your `Form` set to `AutoScroll = true`, `Dock = Fill` and from the `Panel` place all your control like `TextBox`, `label`, `listView` etc..

```
  Private Sub Panel1_MouseEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseEnter
        Panel1.Focus()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Panel1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseWheel
        MessageBox.Show("okay")
  End Sub
```

Comment: Grad to help.. but dont forget check my answer as your accepted answer `:)`